# Unable to access Laravel backend when creating new page?

Tags: php, laravel-5

So basically my site was pre-made so that pages did not exist.  The only features that existed was a directory and some posts.  No pages.  So I had to duplicate the posts function (meaning I replaced all instances of $post and $posts with $page and $pages).  It all worked fine.  I created a test page which worked.  But now I can't access my backend.

This is the URL structure of the pages as seen in the routes file:

```
    Route::get('{url}', 'postsController@viewpage');
```

So it will basically look like this: www.mywebsite.com/pagehere

But the backend's URL structure looks like this: www.mywebsite.com/admin

So I wonder if my page structure is conflicting with the admin backend?

Whenever I try to access the backend, I get redirected to the homepage.

My controller file has this:

```
    public function adminpage(){
        return view ('admin/index')->with("title","Admin");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the rule you put in place matches every route:

```
Route::get('{url}', 'postsController@viewpage');
```

You need to specify that the given url must exclude routes tarting with `admin`, via a regex you can achieve this:

```
Route::get('{url}', 'postsController@viewpage')->where('url', '[^admin]');
```

Also I would advise you to use appropriate naming convations: `PostsController`

Laravel route regex [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#parameters-regular-expression-constraints)

Comment: ok so I can access the admin backend but now the test page broke and says Under Construction.  The URL structure was: example.com/test

Comment: Maybe it's in [maintenance](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/configuration#maintenance-mode) mode?

Comment: You said it was "premade", a platform which is based on Laravel? Existing project? a plugin added in Laravel? Maybe there is an option via a config? Find where the template is requested and work upwards...not much to say being in the dark

Comment: yes, it is based on Laravel. There are lots of pages that have similar URL structure.  eg: /admin/, /articles/, /user/, /schools/.